# Using Hidden Security Icons in Taskdialog

Tags: c#, taskdialog

I am trying to display a Security Success Icon (with the blue background) in TaskDialog message box. This is not one of the enum values of TaskDialogStandardIcon. Reference: http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-new-taskdialog-winapi.

How do I assign these non standard values to ((TaskDialog)sender).Icon ? Is it even possible in C#? C#

Any pointers would be really helpful.

Regards,
Ashwin

Comment: You may want to check out the [Ookii.Dialogs](https://github.com/ookii-dialogs), which implements the `TaskDialog` and others

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you will need to import [`TaskDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760540.aspx) function from `comctl32.dll` yourself:

```
static class TaskDialogWrapper
{
    [DllImport("comctl32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "TaskDialog")]
    static extern int TaskDialog(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hInstance, string pszWindowTitle, string pszMainInstruction, string pszContent, TaskDialogCommonButton dwCommonButtons, IntPtr pszIcon, out IntPtr pnButton);

    public static TaskDialogCommonButton Show(IntPtr handle, IntPtr instance, string title, string instructionText, string content, TaskDialogCommonButton commonButtons, TaskDialogCommonIcon commonIcon)
    {
        IntPtr resultButton;
        if (TaskDialog(handle, instance, title, instructionText, content, commonButtons, new IntPtr((int)commonIcon), out resultButton) != 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        return (TaskDialogCommonButton)resultButton;
    }
}

[Flags()]
enum TaskDialogCommonButton
{
    Ok = 0x1,
    Yes = 0x2,
    No = 0x4,
    Cancel = 0x8,
    Retry = 0x10,
    Close = 0x20
}

enum TaskDialogCommonIcon
{
    ShieldGrey = 65527,
    ShieldOk = 65528,
    ShieldError = 65529,
    ShieldWarning = 65530,
    ShieldBlue = 65531,
    Shield = 65532,
    Information = 65533,
    Error = 65534,
    Warning = 65535,
}
```

To use your own icon from a file, you will need to import [`TaskDialogIndirect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

---

(Btw., I found many other interesting icon styles for `TaskDialogCommonIcon`. You could add e.g.:

```
enum TaskDialogCommonIcon
{
    None = 0,
    Sheet = 2,
    ExplorerFolderOpen = 3,
    ExplorerFolderFlat = 5,
    ExplorerFolderLeft = 6,
    Search = 8,
    ExplorerFolderClosed = 10,
    ExplorerGames = 14,
    Application = 15,
    TransparentSpace = 17,
    ExplorerSearch = 18,
    TextFile = 19,
    Letter = 20,
    Picture = 21,
    Diashow = 103,
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I know this is a bit older, but where did you find these specific enumerations (in your "BTW" section)?  I'd like to see if I can find a complete listing of them somewhere without having to manually identify each one.

I figured out that I can use the WindowsAPICodePack from Nuget (https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack-Core/) to call these by setting the Icon property to a casted value (`CType(65528, TaskDialogCommonIcon)`), and I'd like to try to get as complete a listing as possible.

Comment: I'm afraid to disappoint you, but the way I found out these constants has been trying out them all. Nevertheless, there might exist any DLL storing the same icons in the same order (e. g. imageres? I don't know.) you could google to find out the icon's official meaning.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is an old question, but I was looking for something similar, so I thought I'd pass along what I've found.  Using the information posted by @KnorxThieus, I found a way to use the "hidden" security icons in the TaskDialog without going through the DLLImport process outlined above.  Using the actual values he provided for the `TaskDialogCommonIcon` enumeration, I found that you can simply cast them to the appropriate type (i.e., the `TaskDialogCommonIcon`), and your application should display them properly.

Please note, I'm using the WindowsAPICodePack version 1.1.2 from Nuget (nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack-Core), and the code below has been converted from Visual Basic using the Telerik Code Converter (http://converter.telerik.com/), so it's possible that you may have to do some fine-tuning in C#:

```
if (TaskDialog.IsPlatformSupported) {
    using (TaskDialog dialog = new TaskDialog()) {
        dialog.Caption = "TESTING";
        dialog.InstructionText = "THIS IS A TEST";
        dialog.Text = "This is a test of casting a value to the desired Icon type for a TaskDialog.";

        // Produces the green shield with green background
        dialog.Icon = (TaskDialogStandardIcon)65528;
        dialog.OwnerWindowHandle = this.Handle;
        dialog.Show();
    }
}
```

In my testing, this seems to work for all of the enumerations @KnorxThieus listed, as well as several others.  I'm trying to figure out if there's a similar method for setting the `Icon` property to another (non-standard) image file, but I've been unsuccessful with that so far.  I hope this helps anyone that stumbles across this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Ookii.Dialogs](https://github.com/ookii-dialogs). It implements the `TaskDialog` and others dialogs as well, and have versions targeting [WPF](https://github.com/caioproiete/ookii-dialogs-wpf) and [Windows Forms](https://github.com/caioproiete/ookii-dialogs-winforms).

[image]